# OmitAutoProperties affects non auto property

Tags: autofixture

I have a class that has property like this

```
public string Foo
    {
        get { return _foo; }
        set
        {
            if (!string.Equals(_foo, value))
            {
                _foo= value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I create object with `_fixture = new Fixture {OmitAutoProperties = true};`, I expect it has value but it's null and setter never hit. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. As the documentation states:

> Gets or sets if writable properties should generally be assigned a value when generating an anonymous object.

In other words, in AutoFixture, the term *auto-property* refers the the feature of AutoFixture that automatically populates writable properties. Perhaps a better word would have been `DoNotAutomaticallyPopulateProperties`.

I can understand the confusion, as in C#, *auto-property* can also be interpreted as meaning [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).

Frankly, AutoFixture's terminology should, perhaps, have been chosen with greater care, but in all these years, I don't think this has ever been brought to my attention before.

Specifically in the OP `Foo` is a writable property, and when you disable *auto-properties*, the setter is never invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The `OmitAutoProperties` setting determines if a [*writable* property should be set or not](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Fixture.cs#L203):

> Gets or sets if writable properties should generally be assigned a value when generating an anonymous object.

So, if it's `true`, AutoFixture *does not try* to set any property values and that is by design.